# Where is my Docker Wordpress Website Storing Data?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker

I currently have a Wordpress container set up in Docker, and have it linked to a MySQL database on the same machine (that is **not** in a Docker container). I played around with editing the website in my browser, deleting the Wordpress container, and creating a new one linked to the same database.

When I did this, the sample posts I made on my website persisted, so I assumed my data was being stored by my database locally. However, I then tried setting up multiple websites using Wordpress Multisite using one Wordpress container. To do this, I had to edit the Wordpress config file inside the Wordpress container.

I deleted this container, and created a new one like before. I tried replicating the config changes in this container, however, when I navigate to my website, it just gives me a white screen. This leads me to think that the MySQL database is pointing to empty tables all of a sudden.

Where are my Wordpress templates/info actually being stored?

**EDIT**: Below is the command I run

```
sudo docker run -p 80:80 --name wordpress_local -e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=(machine's IP address) -e WORDPRESS_DB_USER=user -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=password -d wordpress
```

Note:  This is assuming I have a local MySQL database set up that accepts connections from `0.0.0.0` and has a user called `user` with password `password`

I know that my container is properly linking to the database from looking at the logs (and the fact that I can access the website--just get a blank page)

**EDIT 2**: Looking at my Wordpress container filesystem, I can navigate different folders and do see content such as themes/plugins that I have installed. Why is this not being stored on my local machine? (Sorry if this is a dumb question--I am new to both MySQL and Docker)

Comment: can you show your Dockerfile or a reproducer?

Comment: I do not have a Dockerfile, but instead run just one command to get my container running. The only things I have done to my MySQL database is: made sure it was running, and made sure it had a user with privileges to a wordpress db I created

Comment: you can always enter the Wordpress container `docker exec -it container_id bash` and use lsof or such tool to see where it is stored

Comment: is https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/ your docker image?

Comment: @Thomasleveil yes, I believe that is the image I am using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run wordpress container for the first time, the initialization script downloads the wordpress codebase to `/var/www/html` and then start the web server. Since everything inside a container is ephemeral, the codebase with any changes you make will be lost when you re-run the container *(unless you just stop/start the container which is not the best option for this scenario)*.

What you need is to make this folder have persistent data. To achieve this you have to mount a folder from the host machine inside the container:

```
sudo docker run -p 80:80 \
   --name wordpress_local \
  -e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=(machine's IP address) \
  -e WORDPRESS_DB_USER=user \
  -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=password \
  -d \
  -v `pwd`/html:/var/www/html \
  wordpress
```

Don't forget, the folder should be already created: `mkdir -p data`

Comment: I see. However, I still do not understand what purpose my MySQL database has. Shouldn't my database be storing the data in some local directory? Why do I even need a database if I use this method to mount a folder to my machine?

Comment: Also, when you mention "re-running the container", do you mean committing the container to an image and then running the image? The only scenario I would do this is if I decided to push the image to a repository and wanted to run the website on, say, a different machine. In this scenario, wouldn't I still need to copy over the files in the mounted folder on my machine?

Comment: MySQL needs a local directory to store the data (in ubuntu/debian it is placed in /var/lib/mysql) and wordpress container needs a different directory to save the code running, uploads etc. My answers solves the problem of persisting the data of wordpress container.

Comment: As for the "re-running the container", when you _run_ container _from_ an image, you create add a read-write file layer on top the image. This file layer is lost when you kill/delete the container, so when you _run_ again the container a new file layer is created without the data of the lost one. To have this file layer persist you need to use the solution described in my answer. Get more information for containers states [here](https://docs.docker.com/terms/container/)

Comment: You have answered my question, but if I could also ask: what is the point of committing a container to an image if the filesystem will be lost? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: That's a great question. In short, there are 2 practises to persist the data generated in a container. I suggested the simpler one which is to mount volumes from the host. The other option is to use volumes from _ data containers_, aka containers used only to host file changes. Don't hesitate to ask a question for that. I, among others, will be glad to elaborate on this subject.

Comment: Also, check this to read more about data containers: https://medium.com/@ramangupta/why-docker-data-containers-are-good-589b3c6c749e